# JSON parsing from a link

Tags: json, api, rest, parsing

I have been looking at parsing some data from a few different sources. For example, I was looking at this link: http://universities.hipolabs.com/search, and I can filter all Canadian universities just by adding the following key-value pair

```
http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?country=canada
```

I can filter even further just by adding a & key-value pair [&name=acadia] to the end of the link.

How do I do the same say with the Lakers Store? I can get all product metadata in JSON format

```
https://lakersstore.com/products.json
```

but I can't get it filtered like the university list

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter it you should implement the filtering functionality:

1. Pulling the data from link.
2. Converting data to list of elements.
3. Applying your filter on these list.
4. Retrieving the filtered data.

Nice online tool that filter JSON object.

https://jsonpath.com/

Answer (score 0):

The universities example was created specifically to allow searching/filtering data while the lakers site was not. The only solution is to filter the data yourself in your program.

Comment: Can it be done on the fly or do I have to save the data first in order to parse it?

Comment: You will have to save it first. When an api doesn't have any documentation to tell you how to filter data, then chances are you can't filter the data from the url.